# Careers link for guests points to current page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Try logging into an SOFU site as a guest and clicking the **careers** link. For me it just points to the current page.

[image: Screenshot]

**Sites it repros on for me:**

- StackOverflow + Meta
- SuperUser + Meta
- ServerFault + Meta

**Sites it doesn't:**

- Area51 (has no careers link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I made a mistake in the string table here. Fix will go in tomorrow.